# Accessing AWS API Gateway from an EC2 using IAM authorization (NodeJS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

Perhaps I'm going a bridge to far here but heres what I got:

- An AWS API Gateway Method that has AWS_IAM set for Authorization.
- A Policy that allows access to that Method.
- An EC2 Role that has that policy attached to it.
- An EC2 Launched with that Role.

I would like to have my NodeJS program (or any language for that matter) on that EC2 to be able to call that API without hardcoding an AccessKey and SecretKey in the code.

I have used this approach to use the aws-sdk to put/get records on S3, and do other AWS functionality (like all the steps I mentioned above), However, invoking an API Gateway seems to be outside the aws-sdk scope.

Calling the API with Wreck (the NPM I use from my HTTP calls in my app) and no headers results in:

```
{
  "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

Not a big shock there.

Anything obvious I am missing?

Comment: API Gateway has an [SDK Generator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html) that apparently builds/generates a custom SDK specifically for accessing *your* API.  Haven't used it, myself, but you might take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears you need to access your EC2 at `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/Role_Name`

As explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).

Here is my final code including [Signing AWS Requests with Signature Version 4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html):

```
var Moment = require('moment');
var Wreck = require('wreck');
var Crypto = require('crypto');

function getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
    var kDate = Crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'AWS4' + key).update(dateStamp,'utf8').digest();
    var kRegion = Crypto.createHmac('sha256', kDate).update(regionName, 'utf8').digest();
    var kService = Crypto.createHmac('sha256', kRegion).update(serviceName, 'utf8').digest();
    var kSigning = Crypto.createHmac('sha256', kService).update('aws4_request', 'utf8').digest();
    return kSigning;
}

var assumed_role = 'MY_ROLE';
Wreck.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/' + assumed_role, function(err, res, payload) {
    var payload_obj = JSON.parse(payload.toString());
    var access_key = payload_obj.AccessKeyId;
    var secret_key = payload_obj.SecretAccessKey;
    var token = payload_obj.Token;

    var payload = {}
    payload.email = 'devin.stewart@example.com';
    payload.first_name = 'Devin';
    payload.last_name = 'Stewart';
    payload.full_name = 'Devin Stewart';

    var request_parameters = JSON.stringify(payload);

    var method = 'POST';
    var api_id = 'MY_API_ID'
    var service = 'execute-api';
    var region = 'us-east-1';
    var api_path = '/production/people';
    var host = api_id + '.' + service + '.' + region + '.amazonaws.com';
    var endpoint = 'https://' + host + api_path;
    var content_type = 'application/json';

    var t = Moment.utc()
    var amz_date = t.format('YYYYMMDD[T]HHmmss[Z]');
    var date_stamp = t.format('YYYYMMDD'); // Date w/o time, used in credential scope

    var canonical_querystring = '';
    var canonical_headers = 'content-type:' + content_type + '\n' + 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amz_date + '\n' + 'x-amz-security-token:' + token + '\n';
    var signed_headers = 'content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token';
    var payload_hash = Crypto.createHash('sha256').update(request_parameters).digest('hex');
    var canonical_request = method + '\n' + api_path + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash;

    var algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
    var credential_scope = date_stamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request';
    var string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amz_date + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  Crypto.createHash('sha256').update(canonical_request).digest('hex');

    var signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, date_stamp, region, service);
    var signature = Crypto.createHmac('sha256', signing_key).update(string_to_sign, 'utf8').digest('hex');

    authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature;
    var headers = { 
        'Content-Type':content_type,
        'X-Amz-Date':amz_date,
        'X-Amz-Security-Token':token,
        'Authorization':authorization_header
    };

    var options = {headers: headers, payload: request_parameters};
    Wreck.post(endpoint, options, function (err, res, payload) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.data.payload.toString());
        } else {
            console.log(payload.toString());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I mean, I'm glad you found the solution, but... 