# AWS_IAM auth for Lambda invokation from elastic beanstalk through ApiGateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm struggling with aws permissions...

TL/DR : 
I have an elastic beanstalk server which needs to invoke lambda functions hidden behind an Api Gateway. It works fine as long as I don't implement auth on the ApiGateway.

- What I did :

  - Added "AWS_IAM" to the "Method Request" of the appropriate ressource ("/signS3" here) and method (GET here)
  - Added "AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess" strategy to my "Elastic Beanstalk service role" AND to my "Elastic Beanstalk instance profile"
  - Called my ApiGateway "method /ressources" using [nodejs https methods](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html)

    - What I get : **"Missing Authentication Token"...**
    - What it might be ?
  - Maybe I should invoke the ApiGateway using AWS-SDK for the role to be linked with my request ? But I don't find the appropriate method in the sdk documentation
  - I'm doing a mistake with the strategy I must grant... but I don't think so, I'm using default AWS AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess default strategy.

Any ideas ?

==============

Whole story :

- **Business need :** i'm building a **mobile app** with a nodejs backend, and I need my user **to be able to upload file to a S3 bucket**.
- **Technical answer :** use S3 Pre-Signed URL ==> the app send some information about the file to store to my back-end, which get some information for a 1-time upload of the specific file to S3, and send it back to my app, which uploads directly the file to S3. Well synthetised in [the following](http://www.aws-simplified.com/aws/aws-s3/allow-download-of-files-from-amazon-s3-without-giving-access-to-bucket/)

**Not an issue, fully working ! Yeah ! But wait...**

I putted my security hat and looked at the setup : every request from the mobile app goes to Server A (which is hosted on Elastic Beanstalk), which is the entry point of my back-end. At that time, Server A has a config file with AWS keys to configure AWS-SDK in order to access S3. So basically, if my server is compromised for some reason, my security key is leaked. What to do then ?

My answer is to delegate the request to S3 to get the pre-signed URL to an AWS Lambda function, which is invoked through ApiGateway. Then, my lambda function - not exposed to the internet - must be compromised to leak my keys. Security is enhanced... Few moments later, it was up and running, and my app requests goes through this process. **Good, but still not perfect :** it works if I don't put $%#@ Auth in my ApiGateway method !

***Indeed, and that's my issue, I don't manage to get AWS_IAM permissions working.*** ==> look at TL/DR to see how I try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the appropriate signature of your request sent to API Gateway. When you are making a REST request to API Gateway that requires AWS_IAM authentication, you need to sign that request yourself using the credentials from the attached role. Additional details here: [Accessing AWS API Gateway from an EC2 using IAM authorization (NodeJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031759/accessing-aws-api-gateway-from-an-ec2-using-iam-authorization-nodejs)